# Magento: Get visitor log for specific date

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

We're using Magento CE 1.8.1 and trying to create a visitor log for a specific date (if possible?).  Ideally looking to view log of IP addresses.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$visitors = Mage::getModel('log/visitor')->getCollection();

foreach ($visitors as $visitor) {
        var_dump($visitor);
}
```

And the output:

```
object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor)#150 (16) { ["_skipRequestLogging":protected]=> bool(false) ["_eventPrefix":protected]=> string(13) "core_abstract" ["_eventObject":protected]=> string(6) "object" ["_resourceName":protected]=> string(11) "log/visitor" ["_resource":protected]=> NULL ["_resourceCollectionName":protected]=> string(22) "log/visitor_collection" ["_cacheTag":protected]=> bool(false) ["_dataSaveAllowed":protected]=> bool(true) ["_isObjectNew":protected]=> NULL ["_data":protected]=> array(6) { ["visitor_id"]=> string(8) "12454596" ["session_id"]=> string(26) "fkiklsaek2sk9djrae04vou8l7" ["first_visit_at"]=> string(19) "2016-05-02 04:02:42" ["last_visit_at"]=> string(19) "2016-05-02 09:20:43" ["last_url_id"]=> string(8) "15626029" ["store_id"]=> string(1) "1" } ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=> bool(true) ["_origData":protected]=> array(6) { ["visitor_id"]=> string(8) "12454596" ["session_id"]=> string(26) "fkiklsaek2sk9djrae04vou8l7" ["first_visit_at"]=> string(19) "2016-05-02 04:02:42" ["last_visit_at"]=> string(19) "2016-05-02 09:20:43" ["last_url_id"]=> string(8) "15626029" ["store_id"]=> string(1) "1" } ["_idFieldName":protected]=> string(10) "visitor_id" ["_isDeleted":protected]=> bool(false) ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

Doesn't seem like that shows any IP information also not exactly sure how to only query a specific date.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code .. and i want to tell you that .. visitor log table does not store the IP address of visitor , you can only get the following field in log/visitor table :-

1) Visitor Id
2) Session Id
3) First visit at
4) Last visit at
5) last url Id
6) Store Id

You can get the http_user_agent of visitor from the visitor_info table of particular customer

EX:- Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.66 Safari/537.36

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you know how I could translate that into code to get http_user_agent from visitors on a specific date?